# Display multiple views in single page

Tags: django

I have a `Django Webapp` which has a few forms for adding data to the database.
Once this data has been added, I want to present this on a dashboard. So I have views that were written that add the logic for the data to be presented, but as far as i can work out you only map 1 view to a template otherwise the data won't be displayed on the template.

I think there is a way to pass the data as a context, but I can't get my head around how to write this for my view.

A really simple view i have to display events

```
def all_events(request):
        event_list = Event.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'pages/event_list.html',{'event_list': event_list})
```

I'm passing this to `event_list` which works fine. But if I `% include %` on the dashboard I get the `HTML` but not the data, which I now understand is right.

But being an absolute bigger with Django, I could really do with an example of the above which I can then apply to all my other views.

Thanks

HTML Template

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block head_title%}
        <title> Dashboard </title>
{% endblock %}
{% block extra_css %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'libs/toastr/build/toastr.min.css' %}">
        <!-- plugin css -->
        <link href="{% static 'libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />      
        
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="main-content">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- start page title -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="page-title-box d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                            <h1 class="display-4 mb-0">Dashboard</h1>
                            <div class="page-title-right">
                                <ol class="breadcrumb m-0">
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Dashboard</a></li>
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Dashboard</li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
         </div>
         {% include 'pages/event_list.html' %} 
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
    <script src="{% static 'libs/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- init js -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/pages/form-editor.init.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- pristine js -->
    <script src="{% static 'libs/pristinejs/dist/pristine.min.js' %}"></script>  
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please show your template.

Comment: Added HTML Template.

Comment: Its a not a good practice. extents and include will be used for static code (for ex: include a nav bar - menu, include a footer, include a side bar but not the actual data). Try to use every thing for a single view.

Comment: Thanks, Siva. I'll bear that in mind. But how do I present the same view on multiple pages? If a view renders to a template? Otherwise, i have to create the same view multiple times but each one defines a different template?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but just including the pages.html file will not pass the correct context data to the dashboard if it is not in the view connected to the dashboard endpoint.  Django directs an endpoint to a view, the view grabs the context data from the models or creates it, and returns a template with the data.

Your url pattern for the dashboard could look something like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', dashboard_view, name="dashboard"),
]
```

and your view could then look like this

```
def dashboard_view(request):
        event_list = Event.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'path/to/dashboard.html',{'event_list': event_list})
```

Assuming the event_list.html file uses a context data variable correctly like the example shown below, it will be displayed on the dashboard as well.

```
{{ for event in event_list }}
    {{ event.attribute }}
{{ endfor }}
```

What you're passing to the `render()` function is just a dictionary of context data for the templates to use, so as long as the correct data is in that dictionary and the correct variable names from the dictionary are used in the template being rendered, or any templates included within it, it should be displayed.

Hope this helps answer your question!

Comment: Thanks Dichter. The problem i have is that i want the same view displayed on multiple pages. So all_events need to be displayed on the events_list.html. But I'd also want the data shown on the dashboard. This will be the same for maybe 5 or 6 different views. So I could just create 10/12 views to cover this, but that seems wrong

Comment: If you want the same view displayed on multiple pages, all you have to do is connect it to the url pattern.  If I have view `x` and `urlspatterns=[path(..,view=x,...),path(...,view=x,...)`, I can reuse the view as much as I want.  But it seems like you should create an html file with a table of `event_list`s and include it in all the places you want it, then add `Event.objects.all()` to the context data for the responsible view.

Comment: If you use the approach in the answer, it should go from your url -> dashboard_view -> dashboard.html (with event.html included in it).  If I'm misunderstanding your question, please add your url config and your dashboard view to the question.

Comment: Thanks Dichter. I can't get this to work. I have created the event_list.html and then added the `{% include 'pages/event_list.html' %}` to my dashboard, but all get is the table without any data.

Comment: In order to understand why it isn't working, I'd need to see your dashboard url pattern, dashboard view, and the event_list.html file.  If there is no data in the table, it means none is being provided to the template, which can occur for several reasons.  In my experience, the main causes are misuse of context variable names, lack of context data in the view, or HTML mistakes.